# Give $e$ correct to three decimal places using a Maclaurin polynomial

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

I was asked to use Taylor's Theorem to confirm that the Maclaurin polynomial $P_7(x)$ for $e^x$ is sufficient to give $e$ correct to $3$ decimal places. My calculus-book states:

> "To get an approximation for $e=e^1$ correct to 3 decimal places, we
>   need to have $E_n(1)<0.0005$"

QUESTION: I don't see why an error of $0.0005$ is sufficiently small, since $e+0.0005=2.7187...$ which rounds to $2.719$ which is not correct to $3$ decimal places. Any thoughts?

Comment: One possible answer is that the term “correct to 3 decimal places” is just a convenient shorthand for “accuracy better than $0.0005$”. Usually, the accuracy of the calculation is more important than whether a particular digit is correct if you were to continue the decimal expansion. But I agree that the terminology is confusing. If you truly want to know the third decimal for sure, you have to work a bit harder.

Comment: I'm guessing if you don't round, and write the number to four decimal places, 3 of them are right.

Comment: @snulty this is not the case since $e-0.0005=2.7177...$

Comment: @ImreVégh hmm. Fair point

Comment: What is $\;E_n(1)\;$ ??

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Lagrange formula for the remainder in the Taylor Polynomial development of order $\;n\;$ around $\;x_0=0\;$ to evaluate the error :

$$\text{For}\;c\in (0,x)\;:\;\;\left|\frac{f^{(n+1)}(c)}{(n+1)!}x^{n+1}\right|=\frac{e^c}{(n+1)!}|x|^{n+1}\le$$

$$\le\frac{e^c}{(n+1)!}\cdot\le\frac9{(n+1)!}$$

since we can choose $\;x\le1\;$ and estimating crudely $\;e^3\implies e^2<9\;$, and thus we want:

$$\frac9{(n+1)!}\cdot<10^{-3}\implies (n+1)!>9,000\implies n+1=8\implies n=7$$

and indeed:

$$e=1+1+\frac12+\frac16+\frac1{24}+\frac1{120}+\frac1{720}+\frac1{5,040}\approx2.71825$$

and then

$$2-2.71825=0.00002... <10^{-3}$$

It turns out that also $\;n=6\;$ would work, but we usually aren't that interested in *the best or smallest* possible $\;n\;$, but only in *some* value that will work and will be *more or less* close to the best one.

Comment: Why is $e^2< 9$ used why not just use $e<3$